# Como faço para criar essa parte do código e qual parte se encaixaria?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Boa noite, gente! Tudo bem?

Estou tentando desenvolver um projeto que envolve a criação de um círculo interativo com base em ícones que me foram enviadas.
Nesse projeto eu tenho que trabalhar com HTML, CSS, Jquery, podendo utilizar JS, Sass, mas não é obrigatório.
Como faço para unir esses ícones (me foi enviado uma pasta contendo os ícones, uma seta amarela, uma seta cinza, outra azul, um ícone com o círculo completo com essas três cores já unidas)[Esse é o print que eu tirei do ícone de círculo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYU6h.jpg)
Algumas especificações que me foram passadas: quando clicar no botão (+) que está na flecha amarela, a cor de fundo do círculo central deve ser alterada para #FF3737, a cor do texto para #FFF e a seguinte mensagem deve aparecer: "Texto com fundo amarelo"

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Basicamente eu tenho que fazer isso: quando clicar no ícone que tem duas pessoas e uma lâmpada (vide a foto que enviei) que está na flecha amarela, a cor de fundo do círculo central deve ser alterada para #FF3737, a cor do texto para #FFF e a seguinte mensagem deve aparecer: "Texto com fundo amarelo", qualquer dúvida na explicação só perguntar, por gentileza, mas é basicamente só isso que não sei como fazer ao certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Esses são os ícones para adicionar no código: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FaSDEeGYFSui9uA4GF-VRhm5jo2Bv9f_?usp=sharing